# git command not found when calling from cmd in batch script

Tags: python, git, powershell, amazon-ec2

I am working on a automation to spin a ec2 win 2016 instance with git installed and I need to call a powershell script (inside win 2016 instance) from git repository.

To elaborate my requirement:

1. Develop a python script (boto3) to spin a win 2016 ec2 instance
2. Need the following actions to be performed inside "userdata"
   i) install git (by default it won't be available)
   ii) git clone repository
   iii) Execute the powershell script from the local repo.

Below is my python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')

user_data = '''<script>
cd c:/
mkdir software
cd c:/software
echo [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 > download_git.ps1
echo $down = New-Object System.Net.WebClient >> download_git.ps1
echo $url = 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.27.0.windows.1/Git-2.27.0-64-bit.exe' >> download_git.ps1
echo $file = 'C:\software\git.exe' >> download_git.ps1
echo $down.DownloadFile($url,$file) >> download_git.ps1
echo $exec = New-Object -com shell.application >> download_git.ps1
echo exit >> download_git.ps1

powershell "& ""C:\software\download_git.ps1"""

@echo off

set installDir=%1
if [%1]==[] set installDir="C:\Program Files\Git"
set installDir=%installDir:"=%

(
    echo [Setup]
    echo Lang=default
    echo Dir=%installDir%
    echo Group=Git
    echo NoIcons=0
    echo SetupType=default
    echo Components=icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh
    echo Tasks=
    echo PathOption=Cmd
    echo SSHOption=OpenSSH
    echo CRLFOption=CRLFAlways
    echo BashTerminalOption=ConHost
    echo PerformanceTweaksFSCache=Enabled
    echo UseCredentialManager=Enabled
    echo EnableSymlinks=Disabled
    echo EnableBuiltinDifftool=Disabled
) > config.inf

for /r %%f in (git*.exe) do (
    call set file="%%f"
    @echo on
    @echo %%f
    @echo off
)

if [%file%]==[] (
    @echo on
    @echo Error finding "git*.exe" install executable. File may not exist or is not named with the "git" prefix.
    exit /b 2
)

@echo on
@echo Installing..
@echo off
%file% /VERYSILENT /LOADINF="config.inf"
if errorlevel 1 (
    @echo on
    if %errorLevel% == 1 ( echo Error opening %file%. File may be corrupt. )
    if %errorLevel% == 2 ( echo Error reading %file%. May require elevated privileges. Run as administrator. )
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)
del config.inf

net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    setx PATH "%PATH%;%installDir%/cmd;"
    cd c:/
    mkdir gitrepo
    cd c:/gitrepo
    powershell "& ""git clone https://mprukmangathan@bitbucket.org/mprukmangathan/powershell.git"""
    powershell "& ""C:\gitrepo\powershell\install.ps1""" 
) else (
    @echo on
    echo SYSTEM PATH Environment Variable may not be set, may require elevated privileges. Run as administrator if it doesn't already exist.
    exit /b 0
)
</script>'''

response = client.run_instances(
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
            'Ebs': {

                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'VolumeSize': 8,
                'VolumeType': 'gp2'
            },
        },
    ],
    ImageId='ami-0587770c46124f677',
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName='ruk2020',
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    Monitoring={
        'Enabled': False
    },
    SecurityGroupIds=[
        'sg-04a97a6bb4cc46013',
    ],
    TagSpecifications=[ 
        { 
             'ResourceType': 'instance',
             'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'win-git-app'
                },
             ]
        },
    ],
    UserData = user_data
)
```

My script works fine till git installation, but its unable to clone the git repository. Please suggest.

Comment: I think you need to include in the question the error itself when you run your script.

Comment: In addition to providing the exact error text, you should reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the error. See [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).